# Spark Streaming Task Distribution

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have one spark streaming program that uses `updateStateByKey`.
When I run it on a cluster with 3 machines, all `updateStateByKey` tasks (these are heavy tasks) run on one machine. This results in a scheduling delay on inputs, while other machines have idle CPU's.

I changed the number of workers but all `updateStateByKey` tasks run on workers on one specific machine. I also tried using `mapWithState` instead `updateStateByKey` but have the same problem.

How can I tell spark to preferentially distribute tasks across all machines?

```
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> streamEvents = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, eventTopic
    );

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> newKeys = streamEvents.flatMapToPair(new KeyGenerator(zookeeperHosts));

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> scenarioKeys =
            newKeys.updateStateByKey(new HeavyKeysFunc(), 36);
```

The jobs are queued and cpus are approximately idle.

Comment: Did you check the Spark UI to see how many partitions each RDD has?

Comment: How are you creating your streaming job (streaming source)? Could you add the code?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes! i change up the number of partition to 36 but have the same problem.

Comment: @maasg I use `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` that read from Kafka with 2 partition on a separate machines.

Comment: Add your code so we can attempt to help.